# Scale SCNNode in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have the following `SCNNode`:

```
let box = SCNBox(width: 10.0, height: 10.0, length: 10.0, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
```

If I apply:

```
boxNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5)
```

it appears to have no effect on the size of the box. I've checked this with `boxNode.getBoundingBoxMin(&v1, max: &v2)`. It's always the same and appears the same on-screen.

Am I missing something? The docs imply that setting the scale should affect the node's geometry and thus be a different size.

Thanks.
J.

Answer (score 9):

I just tested in a playground and it worked perfectly for me. Perhaps your camera is zooming in to compensate for the smaller box?

```
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground

let sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600))

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = sceneView

var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.backgroundColor = SKColor.greenColor()
sceneView.debugOptions = .ShowWireframe

// default lighting
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

// a camera
var cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 15, y: 15, z: 30)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let box = SCNBox(width: 10.0, height: 10.0, length: 10.0, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
let centerConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: boxNode)
cameraNode.constraints = [centerConstraint]

let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 4)
let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x:15, y:0, z:0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

//boxNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5)
```

Uncomment the last line and you'll see the box (10 x 10 x 10) switch switch from being larger than the sphere (diameter of 8) to being smaller than the sphere. Here it is after the scaling:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Interesting but when I run that (tested on different machines) it takes quiet a while to run (60 sec for sure) and I get the first image (shows above). If I uncomment the line I just get a white box. If I run it in an iOS Playground I get something that looks like an open GL exception.

I'm using Xcode 7.2, OS/X 10.11.2

Comment: Yeah, SceneKit Playgrounds have severe performance problems on some machines. I ran in an OS X playground. File a Radar (bugreport.apple.com) with a system profile (control-option-command-shift-period) and attach the playground. Are you setting up a camera explicitly, or just using the default SceneView camera? What happens if you put two nodes in your scene and scale only one of them?

Comment: I ran this in an iOS app and it worked as expected. For some reason Playgrounds aren't rendering it correctly. I wish I had though to do that earlier :). I must have a bad DAE file because I can scale cubes and spheres but not a model I'm importing. Thx Again.

Comment: Hello! this post was super useful! Any way we can do this with a duration to see it scale?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is not about the visual size, which is what you are showing, but about the value of the bounding box, try printing the boxNode.boundingBox to see that your scaling doesn't affect it. as per Apple documentation a bounding box is using local coordinate space, and so will never change